# Round Robin Scheduling Algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, round-robin

i implemented RR scheduling algorithm with arrival time in javascript. but it have some issues. it is not give the right answer. process queue show correctly

```
    function roundrobin(p,a,b,n){
        var seq=[]
        var res_b=[];
        var res_a=[];
        for (var x = 0; x <b.length; x++) {
                res_b[x] = b[x]; 
                res_a[x] = a[x]; 
            }    
        var t=0;
        var w=[];
        var comp=[];
        while(true){
            var flag=true;
            for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++){
                if (res_a[i]<=t){
                    if(res_a[i]<=n){
                        if(res_b[i]>0){
                            flag=false;
                            if (res_b[i] > n) { 

                                t = t + n; 
                                res_b[i] = res_b[i] - n; 
                                res_a[i] = res_a[i] + n; 
                                seq.push(p[i]); 
                            } 
                            else { 
                                t = t + res_b[i];  
                                comp[i] = t - a[i];  
                                w[i] = t - b[i] - a[i]; 
                                res_b[i] = 0; 
                                seq.push(p[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (res_a[i] > n) { 
                        for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) { 

                            if (res_a[j] < res_a[i]) { 
                                if (res_b[j] > 0) { 
                                    flag = false; 
                                    if (res_b[j] > n) { 
                                        t = t + n; 
                                        res_b[j] = res_b[j] - n; 
                                        res_a[j] = res_a[j] + n; 
                                        seq.push(p[j]); 
                                    } 
                                    else { 
                                        t = t + res_b[j]; 
                                        comp[j] = t - a[j]; 
                                        w[j] = t - b[j] - a[j]; 
                                        res_b[j] = 0; 
                                        seq.push(p[j]); 
                                    } 
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 

                        if (res_b[i] > 0) { 
                            flag = false;  
                            if (res_b[i] > n) { 
                                t = t + n; 
                                res_b[i] = res_b[i] - n; 
                                res_a[i] = res_a[i] + n; 
                                seq.push(p[i]); 
                            } 
                            else { 
                                t = t + res_b[i]; 
                                comp[i] = t - a[i]; 
                                w[i] = t - b[i] - a[i]; 
                                res_b[i] = 0; 
                                seq.push(p[i]);
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                }
                else if (res_a[i] > t) { 
                    t++; 
                    i--; 


            }
        }
        if (flag) { 
            break; 
        } 

        }
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = seq;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = w;
        document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = comp;
    }
```

give me some suggestion to the right implementation. (i worked on this code many days)
Round robin  is the  scheduling algorithm used by the CPU during execution of the process . Round robin is designed specifically for time sharing systems . It is similar to first come first serve scheduling algorithm but the preemption  is the added functionality to switch between the processes